# easypg wants to encrypt authinfo.gpg with my expired key

Tags: gpg

I have a `.authinfo.gpg` that I've previously encrypted with a private key.  That key has expired so I created a new key for myself.  However, I now can't save edits to `authinfo.gpg` because it keeps wanting to use the expired key.  How can I tell easypg to use my new key?